# Creating a DB factory using kotlin

Tags: kotlin, factory-pattern, companion-object

So I'm trying to create a MongoDB factory with kotlin... but I think I don't really understand the concept of `companion object` very well because I can't even get this to compile:

```
package org.jgmanzano.storage

import com.mongodb.MongoClient
import com.mongodb.MongoClientURI
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase

class MongoConnectionFactory(private val connectionURI: String) {
    private var database: MongoDatabase

    init {
        val connectionString = MongoClientURI(connectionURI)
        val mongoClient = MongoClient(connectionString)
        database = mongoClient.getDatabase("paybotDB")
    }

    companion object {
        fun getDatabase() : MongoDatabase {
            return database
        }
    }
}
```

How would you guys achieve this? My idea is to create what in Java would be a kind of *factory method*. I can't seem to get the syntax right tho.

Furthermore, would this be a correct approach to DB connection factories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move everything to the companion object, pass the connection URI to the getDatabase method.
Companion objects get compiled as a static field inside the containing (outer class). Since the field is static, it cannot access outer class's fields because the outer class is an instance.

I assume you want to cache database objects.

```
class MongoConnectionFactory() {

    companion object {
        private var database: MongoDatabae? = null

        fun getDatabase(connectionURI: String) : MongoDatabase {
            if (database != null) {
                return database
            {
            val connectionString = MongoClientURI(connectionURI)
            val mongoClient = MongoClient(connectionString)
            database = mongoClient.getDatabase("paybotDB")
            return database
        }
    }
}
```

But then you don't need a companion object nested inside containing class.
You can create an object instead.

```
object MongoConnectionFactory {
    private var database: MongoDatabae? = null

    fun getDatabase(connectionURI: String) : MongoDatabase {
        if (database != null) {
            return database
        {
        val connectionString = MongoClientURI(connectionURI)
        val mongoClient = MongoClient(connectionString)
        database = mongoClient.getDatabase("paybotDB")
        return database
    }
}
```

If you need multiple databases with different connection URIs then store them inside the hash table.